# UDP Proxy Configuration

Tags: windows, proxy, configuration, udp

I developed a UDP proxy according to [this git project](https://github.com/Stormancer/netproxy.), and now looking for the way to configure the udp proxy in my computer so I can track UDP requests.

I know how to configure a TCP proxy, is there a similar way to configure a UDP proxy?

OS is Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: If you developed it why don't you know how to configure it? and how would anybody else know anything about it?

Comment: Maybe I can resemble it to knowing how to write a C# project but not how to add it as a reference to another project....but this I know well...thanks anyway

Comment: You can liken it to anything you like but it still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a generic system wide UDP proxy. The project you use is essentially a forwarder which listen on some local IP,port and forwards to a predefined remote IP,port. This means you have to setup your specific UDP application to not talk to the remote IP but to your local IP instead. How this is done depends on your specific UDP application.

> ...  so I can track UDP requests.

For tracking traffic this proxy might even be the wrong approach. Try using a packet sniffer like Wireshark instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer.This means that for each and every app using udp protocol I need to configure the local UDP proxy? And regarding "tracking traffic" this is not enough for me becaוse sometimes the code should block the request and should not forward it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: *"This means that for each and every app using udp protocol I need to configure the local UDP proxy?"* - correct. And it will only be possible if the app has a fixed destination IP,port in the first place. *"...not enough for me becaוse sometimes the code should block the request and should not forward it."* - that's actually the job of a firewall.

Comment: can a firewall be dynamic? e.g.: once a user is using an app more than 2 hours a day (in aggregate) I want to block his access to that app for today (tomorrow will start a new counting)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: there is no "the firewall" but various kinds of firewalls. It would be in theory possible to implement something like this but I don't know any product which implements this specific requirement. Anyway, this is out of scope of this question. But you might try to do a question where you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve (i.e. not only your specific approach) and maybe ask at [security.se] in case this problem is security related.